# Solving a system with a given constraint on the variable in maxima

Tags: maxima

I have the following system I'm trying to solve:

```
assume(x>0);
solve([x^2 = 3], x);
```

I expected that the answer would be `[x=sqrt(3)]`, but maxima also gives the negative solution `[x=-sqrt(3),x=sqrt(3)]`. Is it possible to specify that the domain of `x` here is all positive real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, (not yet tested in other cases):

```
assume(x>0)$
sublist(
    solve(x^2=3,x), 
    lambda(
        [point],
        facts: subst(point, facts(initial)), 
        every(lambda([fact], is(fact)), facts)
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, something of this kind is necessary, because `solve` does not apply assumptions to the solutions; this is another of the limitations of `solve`.